# Wordpress subdomain wp-admin redirects to main domain

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, subdomains

we have a wordpress installation running on address www.example.com.
We wanted to have a development site for it as a subdomain, so we created a subdomain dev.example.com on cpanel.
Created a duplicate of its database and replicated the files to the directory root of dev.example.com.
Then modified wp-config.php to point to the duplicate db.
Now the problem is, when we try to access dev.example.com/wp-admin, it redirects to https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: When you copied the database, did you change the site url to the sub domain? It is usually the first record in the `wp_options` table.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson Actually, I'm using this http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to change wp_options and wp_posts url to my new url. Still no luck, I'm dumping my db now to check again for any occurences of my old url.

Comment: Check your theme files too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Charles Clarkson's comment, I directly changed the `siteurl` and `home` options in the `wp_options` table to be `https://dev.example.com/` and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I created a subdomain with its own database on our server, just under our main (https://example.com/newsite). It had been working fine for one month. During some API testing for integration the "newsite" wp-admin kept redirecting to the main site's login whenever you tried to access the "newsite" login. Checked the newsite's database (in table wp-options)and sure enough, the siteurl and home had been changed to https://example.com , I changed them both back to https://example.com/newsite and everything works find now.